# Extend an array with data from another array after a specific occurrence

Tags: python, arrays, datetime

I would like to extend the content of an array with content from a different array after a certain `"DEPARTURE DATE"` and `"DEPARTURE TIME"` has occurred, in particular the newest departure date and time.

These is an exert from the two arrays I compare.

```
alilauro_live_departures_data = [{"COMPANY": "Alilauro", "DEPARTURE PORT": "Napoli Molo Beverello", "ARRIVAL PORT": "Ischia", "DEPARTURE DATE": "2019-02-18", "DEPARTURE TIME": "20:20", "ARRIVAL DATE": "2019-02-18", "ARRIVAL TIME": "21:40", "DURATION": "01:20:00", "FERRY TYPE": "Aliscafo", "STATUS": "Active"}, {"COMPANY": "Alilauro", "DEPARTURE PORT": "Ischia", "ARRIVAL PORT": "Napoli Molo Beverello", "DEPARTURE DATE": "2019-02-19", "DEPARTURE TIME": "06:30", "ARRIVAL DATE": "2019-02-19", "ARRIVAL TIME": "07:20", "DURATION": "00:50:00", "FERRY TYPE": "Aliscafo", "STATUS": "Active"}]

alilauro_timetable = [{"COMPANY": "Alilauro", "DEPARTURE PORT": "Forio", "ARRIVAL PORT": "Napoli Molo Beverello", "DEPARTURE DATE": "2019-02-19", "DEPARTURE TIME": "06:45", "ARRIVAL DATE": "2019-02-19", "ARRIVAL TIME": "08:05", "DURATION": "01:20:00", "FERRY TYPE": "Aliscafo", "STATUS": "Active"}, {"COMPANY": "Alilauro", "DEPARTURE PORT": "Napoli Molo Beverello", "ARRIVAL PORT": "Ischia", "DEPARTURE DATE": "2019-02-19", "DEPARTURE TIME": "07:05", "ARRIVAL DATE": "2019-02-19", "ARRIVAL TIME": "08:25", "DURATION": "01:20:00", "FERRY TYPE": "Aliscafo", "STATUS": "Active"}, {"COMPANY": "Alilauro", "DEPARTURE PORT": "Napoli Molo Beverello", "ARRIVAL PORT": "Forio", "DEPARTURE DATE": "2019-02-19", "DEPARTURE TIME": "07:05", "ARRIVAL DATE": "2019-02-19", "ARRIVAL TIME": "08:25", "DURATION": "01:20:00", "FERRY TYPE": "Aliscafo", "STATUS": "Active"}]
```

I search `alilauro_live_departures_data` for the newest departure

```
newest_departure_date = max((datetime.strptime(it["DEPARTURE DATE"]+it["DEPARTURE TIME"], "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M") for it in alilauro_live_departures_data))
newest_departure_date_str = datetime.strftime(newest_departure_date, "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M")
```

I then search for the occurrence in `alilauro_timetable`

```
re.search(alilauro_newest_departure, it["DEPARTURE DATE"]+it["DEPARTURE TIME"]) for it in alilauro_timetable)
```

How do I proceed to extend `alilauro_live_departures_data` with all departures data after `newest_departure_date` in this example `2019-02-19 06:30`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below scans 'ali_timetable' for new entries and add them to 'ali_live_departures_data'

```
import datetime
import pprint

ali_live_departures_data = [
{"COMPANY": "Alilauro", "DEPARTURE PORT": "Napoli Molo Beverello", "ARRIVAL PORT": "Ischia",
 "DEPARTURE DATE": "2019-02-18", "DEPARTURE TIME": "20:20", "ARRIVAL DATE": "2019-02-18", "ARRIVAL TIME": "21:40",
 "DURATION": "01:20:00", "FERRY TYPE": "Aliscafo", "STATUS": "Active"},
{"COMPANY": "Alilauro", "DEPARTURE PORT": "Ischia", "ARRIVAL PORT": "Napoli Molo Beverello",
 "DEPARTURE DATE": "2019-02-19", "DEPARTURE TIME": "06:30", "ARRIVAL DATE": "2019-02-19", "ARRIVAL TIME": "07:20",
 "DURATION": "00:50:00", "FERRY TYPE": "Aliscafo", "STATUS": "Active"}]

ali_timetable = [{"COMPANY": "Alilauro", "DEPARTURE PORT": "Forio", "ARRIVAL PORT": "Napoli Molo Beverello",
              "DEPARTURE DATE": "2019-02-19", "DEPARTURE TIME": "06:45", "ARRIVAL DATE": "2019-02-19",
              "ARRIVAL TIME": "08:05", "DURATION": "01:20:00", "FERRY TYPE": "Aliscafo", "STATUS": "Active"},
             {"COMPANY": "Alilauro", "DEPARTURE PORT": "Napoli Molo Beverello", "ARRIVAL PORT": "Ischia",
              "DEPARTURE DATE": "2019-02-19", "DEPARTURE TIME": "07:05", "ARRIVAL DATE": "2019-02-19",
              "ARRIVAL TIME": "08:25", "DURATION": "01:20:00", "FERRY TYPE": "Aliscafo", "STATUS": "Active"},
             {"COMPANY": "Alilauro", "DEPARTURE PORT": "Napoli Molo Beverello", "ARRIVAL PORT": "Forio",
              "DEPARTURE DATE": "2019-02-19", "DEPARTURE TIME": "07:05", "ARRIVAL DATE": "2019-02-19",
              "ARRIVAL TIME": "08:25", "DURATION": "01:20:00", "FERRY TYPE": "Aliscafo", "STATUS": "Active"}]

newest_departure_date = max(
    (datetime.datetime.strptime(it["DEPARTURE DATE"] + it["DEPARTURE TIME"], "%Y-%m- 
        %d%H:%M") for it in
                  ali_live_departures_data))
for time_table_entry in ali_timetable:
    entry_date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    time_table_entry["DEPARTURE DATE"] + time_table_entry["DEPARTURE TIME"], "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M")
    if entry_date_time > newest_departure_date:
        ali_live_departures_data.append(time_table_entry)

pprint.pprint(ali_live_departures_data)
```

Output:

```
[{'ARRIVAL DATE': '2019-02-18',
  'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Ischia',
  'ARRIVAL TIME': '21:40',
  'COMPANY': 'Alilauro',
  'DEPARTURE DATE': '2019-02-18',
  'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Napoli Molo Beverello',
  'DEPARTURE TIME': '20:20',
  'DURATION': '01:20:00',
  'FERRY TYPE': 'Aliscafo',
 'STATUS': 'Active'},
{'ARRIVAL DATE': '2019-02-19',
 'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Napoli Molo Beverello',
 'ARRIVAL TIME': '07:20',
 'COMPANY': 'Alilauro',
 'DEPARTURE DATE': '2019-02-19',
 'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Ischia',
 'DEPARTURE TIME': '06:30',
 'DURATION': '00:50:00',
 'FERRY TYPE': 'Aliscafo',
 'STATUS': 'Active'},
 {'ARRIVAL DATE': '2019-02-19',
  'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Napoli Molo Beverello',
  'ARRIVAL TIME': '08:05',
  'COMPANY': 'Alilauro',
  'DEPARTURE DATE': '2019-02-19',
  'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Forio',
  'DEPARTURE TIME': '06:45',
  'DURATION': '01:20:00',
  'FERRY TYPE': 'Aliscafo',
  'STATUS': 'Active'},
 {'ARRIVAL DATE': '2019-02-19',
  'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Ischia',
  'ARRIVAL TIME': '08:25',
  'COMPANY': 'Alilauro',
  'DEPARTURE DATE': '2019-02-19',
  'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Napoli Molo Beverello',
  'DEPARTURE TIME': '07:05',
  'DURATION': '01:20:00',
  'FERRY TYPE': 'Aliscafo',
  'STATUS': 'Active'},
 {'ARRIVAL DATE': '2019-02-19',
  'ARRIVAL PORT': 'Forio',
  'ARRIVAL TIME': '08:25',
  'COMPANY': 'Alilauro',
  'DEPARTURE DATE': '2019-02-19',
  'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Napoli Molo Beverello',
  'DEPARTURE TIME': '07:05',
  'DURATION': '01:20:00',
  'FERRY TYPE': 'Aliscafo',
  'STATUS': 'Active'}]
```